# correct path for enqueue script in WordPress

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I have this action:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_script_load3' );
function my_custom_script_load3(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-script3', '/members/user.js' );
}
```

It works great when I have it in functions.php of my root directory WordPress installation.

But I also have a second WordPress installation which is in it's own directory, on the root:

/second-wordpress-site/

I have this action also installed in this second WordPress site in functions.php

In this second WordPress site, the action keeps pulling the script up like:

/second-wordpress-site/members/user.js

instead of how it should be:

/members/user.js

Any suggestions on the correct syntax for the site, so the path is correct?

I've tried several path variations, with no luck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: /members/user.js is from a standalone membership plugin, located on the root of site. It seems like the path I have in action should pull up this script, but it's adding the WordPress installation path in front of the script: /second-wordpress-site/members/user.js

Comment: Can‘t you just use URLs instead of relative paths?

Comment: swissspidy - I tried that before and it didn't work, but the second time it worked great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your second WordPress installation accessible using URL? If yes then you can use the following tricks

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'op_enqueue_scripts');
function op_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-script-from-2nd-site',
        'http://my-second-wp-installation.com/members/user.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '1.0',
        true
    );
}
```

Comment: obiPlabon - thanks for reply. I'm trying to access /members/user.js (path starts from the root) FROM the second WP installation in /second-wordpress-site/. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Given snippet will only work if your 2nd WP installation is accessible using a URL. It doesn't matter if it's in your installation's root directory.

Like if your 1st installation is accessible using http://example1.com then is it possible to access your 2nd installation using http://example2.com or http://example1.com/2ndWP/ or http://2ndwp.example1.com ?

Comment: Yes, but the script I need to access isn't located at http://my-second-wp-installation.com/members/user.js. The script is located at http://mysite.orgg/members/user.js. Would your action still apply for this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `my-second-wp-installation.com/` used this as an example of your 2nd installation's domain name, didn't mean exact thing. If your script is under your 2nd installation and the path is `member/user.js` and is relative to installation directory then my method will work.

Comment: obiPlabon - swissspidy's solution worked, but thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: That's what I was telling to you all the time! :D

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this its work for me :)

```
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
  function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() .'/javascipt/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', TRUE);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() .'/javascipt/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', TRUE);
  }
```

Comment: Abhay, I appreciate it, but the script "/members/user.js" on my site is not in WordPress. It's in a standalone membership script. It looks like the scripts you are pulling are inside of WordPress, which wouldn't work for me.